# "though" vs "although"

Tags: grammar, meaning, conjunctions

I do not understand the grammatical differences between "*though*" and "*although*".

Can we use them interchangeably?

Comment: Did you check the dictionary definitions to get an idea about the similarities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although they may seem confusing, most of the time, 'although' and 'though' mean the same thing. 'Although' might be slightly more formal, though. In my first sentence, I can easily change 'although' to 'though' ('Though they may seem confusing ...'). In my second sentence, I can't use 'although'.This shows that 'though' has at least one extra use - at the end of a clause, by itself. Other uses include the phrases 'even though' and 'as though'.  If you remember one word to use in your speaking or writing, remember and use 'though' - it is used in more ways, and is (slightly) more common.